# Touch events acting strangely

Tags: java, android

UPDATE:
So I figured out that it was because the MotionEvent was being changed after I passed it to the thread, the solution was this:

```
/**
* Standard override to get touch screen motion events.
*/
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    MotionEvent passMe = MotionEvent.obtain(event);
    event.recycle();
    return thread.doTouchEvent(passMe);
}
```

but somehow I end up with event and passMe having the same MotionEvent id, for some reason a new MotionEvent isn't created.

What did I do wrong? :(

---vvv OLD vvv---

I'm developing an Android app and I have this code here that adds any touch inputs of action type ACTION_DOWN to a queue:

```
/** Adds the touch event to the motionEventQueue for processing. */
public boolean doTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    //Only add the MotionEvent to the queue if we care about that kind of action.
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        motionEventQueue.add(event);
    }

    return true;
}
```

The problem is that this code here should make sure that only MotionEvents of action type ACTION_DOWN get into the queue, but somehow I'm ending up with MotionEvents of type ACTION_UP and others inside the queue.

Why is this happening? Looking at the debugger it appears that when they're added to the queue they are of type ACTION_DOWN but when it comes time to process the queue the action types seem to have changed somehow.

EDIT: Here is my onTouchEvent method:

```
/**
* Standard override to get touch screen motion events.
*/
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    return thread.doTouchEvent(event);
}
```

EDIT: Does it have to do with the fact that I'm using more than one thread? Is it unsynchronizing or something?

Comment: Do you call recycle() on the event?

Comment: Is it the name of the method?  There is no "doTouchEvent" in the SDK that I can find.  Other than that, my "onTouchEvent" methods are structured just like your example, and seem to work fine in SDK 2.2 and 2.3.   Also, are you absolutely sure "motionEventQueue" is not added to elsewhere?

Comment: doTouchEvent is just the method inside the thread that the onTouchEvent in the view tells the thread to execute.

Also I don't call recycle() on the event, was I supposed to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Events are recycled. You're passed a reference to the event, and you're adding a reference to your queue. The event will be recycled, so your reference points to a new event that was recycled using the old event. If you're lucky.

You shouldn't use the event after the execution of `onTouchEvent` has finished. If you need to store some of its data persistently, copy it to your own structure (or clone the event, if that's possible).

As to your other question - only the UI thread handles touch events, so having multiple threads shouldn't matter (unless of course you use those other threads to torpedo your queue).

Comment: Ah that was it! Thanks for the info. Also, you can clone a MotionEvent using MotionEvent.obtain(event) which returns a new MotionEvent based off of event.

Comment: I wouldn't recycle the event that's passed in. Leave that up to the framework.